# variable going into the wrong position in arrayList

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an arrayList with 500 null Integers in it so I can add a value in whichever position I want:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
array.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[500]));
```

My problem is when I add an Integer in the 8th position, it pushes all the Integers that after it to the next position. Example: I have an Integer at position 5 and another at position 8, if I add one at position 7 the one that was in position 8 moves to position 9. This effect is ruinning my loop.

Adding: `array.add(position, mInt);`

Can someone help?

Comment: what about the one that was already in position 9 ?

Comment: What behavior would you rather see? Do you want to `set` the index instead of moving it back?

Comment: @Blackbelt moves to 10th

Comment: Look at the JavaDoc for [`add(int, E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-). Then look at the JavaDoc for [`set(int,E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-).

Comment: @Zircon I'd rather have the Integers stay in the position they are first added

Comment: Hint: you are expect to do some prior research: like reading the javadoc for the classes you are using. You really shouldn't use stackoverflow as a "shortcut".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to overwrite the integer at given position use `set(index, data)` instead of `add`.

[`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-) is for adding data to array, so it won't replace exiting one, from javadocs:

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). **Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices)**.

[`set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) is for replacing existing data at given index with new data, from javadoc:

> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element (optional operation).

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is when I add an Integer in the 8th position, it pushes all the Integers that after it to the next position.

This is exaclty how add() works:

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
>   Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
>   subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)

If you wanto change in place, use [set()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)) instead:

> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the
>   specified element.